# Insert SQL query con AJAX y ASP.Net

Tags: sql, ajax, sql-server, asp.net

Hola necesito hacer un INSERT de SQL utilizando ajax en ASP.NET, no estoy muy seguro que me esta faltando.

```js
$('#submit').click(function () {
    insertFeedback();
});

function insertFeedback()
{
    var modelx = new Object();

    var depS = document.getElementById("resultDep");
    var catS = document.getElementById("resultCat");
    var schemS = document.getElementById("schemes");
    var wiw = document.getElementById("wiw").value;

    modelx.wiw = wiw;

    var dp  = depS.options[depS.selectedIndex].value;
    modelx.dep = dp;

    var ct = catS.options[catS.selectedIndex].value;
    modelx.cat = ct;
   
    var sch  = schemS.options[schemS.selectedIndex].value;
    modelx.schem = sch;

    var randid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
    modelx.id = randid;

   // modelx.file = $('#formato').val();

    alert(modelx.wiw + "/" + modelx.dep + "/" + modelx.cat + "/" + modelx.schem +
        "/ route: /" + "/" + modelx.id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Url.Action("CreateRequest", "Home")',
        data: modelx,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hi");
            // your code
            $('#sucess').removeClass('hidden');

        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('#error').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    })
   }
```

Hasta aquí no tengo problema en jalar todos los datos que necesito del usuario. Mi problema imagino ha de estar por aquí del lado del servidor. Pero la conosla no me imprime ningun error.

```js
  [WebMethod]
    public JsonResult CreateRequest(Requests modelx)
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql =
            "INSERT INTO [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests]"+
            "([Id],[Wiw],[UserId],[Project],[SchemeId],[Status],"+
            "[ExpirationDays],[Comments],[DepartmentId]"+
            ",[CategoryId],[seen],[Light],[Edit],[CreateDate],"+
            "[SeenDate],[SendDate],[AnswerDate]"+
            ",[EditDate],[Sent],[Approved],[Rejected])"+
            "VALUES"+
            "(@id,'@wiw',333,'test me and thn',@scheme,'En espera',3,'none'" +
            ",@department ,@category,0,1,0,'none' ,'none'" +
            ",'none' ,'none','none',0,0,0)"       
        ;

      
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", modelx.Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", modelx.Wiw);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmen", modelx.DepartmentId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", modelx.CategoryId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scheme", modelx.SchemeId);

                con.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Check Error
                if (result < 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
                }
                    
            } 

           
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "all good fella" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          

        }
        // End GetCategories
    }
```

Muchas grácias a toda la comunidad. Son geniales :)

Comment: Encierra el código c# en un bloque `try/catch`. ¿tienes algún error al ejecutar este código?, si es así, [edit] tu pregunta y agrega la descripción del error.

Comment: No tengo problemas con mi código, solo necesito pasarle los parametros de **model** de manera propia a mi query del lado del servidor .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si pueda funcionar, aún es complicado para mi dar respuestas sin tener el codigo frente de mi ejecutándose correctamente pero utiliza esto data: JSON.PARSE(modelx) dentro del llamado AJAX

Comment: Hola parsear el modelx no me funcionó hay algo que pueda postear para ayudarte a entender mejor mi problema?